# Stripe test payments do not show up in dashboard

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using a PHP Stripe Payment form to collect payments. The payments seem be going through OK and take the user to the confirmation page upon successful completion. I am in test mode and am able to see the payments as they show up in the 'Payments' section of the dashboard. However, when I click on the 'Home' section of the dashboard, I do not see them under the 'Gross volume' tab. There are no error logs created by my code. Also, the Stripe dashboard shows no errors as well. Does it usually take a while for the payments to shown up in the dashboard (even in the test mode)? Or it there something else?

Here's what I have tried after researching on the Internet - clearing browser cache. It worked and showed some of the payments, but its not showing the new charges under the 'Gross Volume' tab, though they show up OK in the 'Payments' section of the dashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You're most likely only creating Tokens but not using those Tokens to create Charges on the server side.

You'll need to make sure you're creating both the Token - using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) - and then the Charge: https://stripe.com/docs/charges

If that's not causing the problem, you'll want to reach out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) so they can look into the details for you.

Comment: Thanks floatingLomas. I went through Stripe's knowledge base and the solution was to simply delete all the test data. That did the trick! I can now see my payment amounts in the dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear out all test data.

- Login to your Stripe account
- Business Settings
- Data
- Look for **Test data**
- Click **Delete all test data**

Go back to your dashboard and click on Payments. Your non-test data will appear.

This is a strange work-a-round because, if I searched for the know good order, the order would show up. So somehow deleting the test data allows the order to appear in the Payment List without doing a search.